# What comes after Microsoft Silverlight for ASP.Net developers?

Tags: asp.net, .net, silverlight, graphics

I worked in the past -- specifically back in 2008 to 2010-- with Silverlight applications within ASP.NET . Now in 2015 I need to develop a new 2D/3D graphical tool within ASP.NET, but I just read that Silverlight will be deprecated in the near future.

Does anyone know what is the next tool that will replace Silverlight for development of graphics and Computer-aided design in ASP.NET?

Comment: I'm sure many might be doing it in HTML5 http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000802/ch01.html#d_coordinate_systems

Comment: Google is not supporting silverlight plug-in anymore(by default)

Comment: Thank for notifying me about Chrome... this really depreciates the value of Silverlight, specially since it's the most used browser as of 2015: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp

Comment: Thanks Kenny, I know nothing about HTML5 but I've come across many posts mentioning it, so I think I'd better start studying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe silverlight is still a good option. The official end of life for Microsoft Silverlight version 5 is **October 12, 2021**.  You have time. That isn't '**too near**' really. If you are to create desktop application, you can then think of using WPF. Your silverlight experience would also help you with that and it is a pretty mature technology.

Comment: But you forgot about the risks on IE side. When they announced the end of life date, it was not clear which version of IE/Firefox/Chrome/Safari is going to support Silverlight apps. It can be that in the near future you only get IE, and that still kills your end user experience.

Comment: @LexLi was a little on the prescient side there. (We're now in IE-only land, which is a horrible place to be. Silverlight is very clearly not a good option in 2019. imo. ;^D )

Comment: @ruffin but after 4 years, C# is back to browsers via Blazor. So if you still want the benefits of Silverlight (C#, CLR and so on), take a look at Blazor, https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/web-apps/blazor